# php вызов приватного метода из статического

Tags: php

Есть класс, с такими методами.

```
private function GetBannerInf() {
        return 123;
    }

    static function GetPathBanner() {
        return $this->GetBannerInf();
    }
```

Не работает. выдает ошибку  Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context ...

Но если написать так: return self::GetBannerInf();

Вопрос 1, почему работает self::GetBannerInf(); если метод GetBannerInf() не статичный.
Вопрос 2, почему первый вариант не работает через this ?

Comment: я конечно не пхпшник, но откуда у статической функции `this`? На то она и статическая, что может быть вызвана даже по имени класс, без объекта.

Comment: спасибо братаны, рукопожимаю. А как в моем случае правильнее будет скрыть GetBannerInf, и вызвать его через статический GetPathBanner ?

Comment: как вариант тоже сделать статическим.

Comment: Статическим и приватным? это как?

Comment: Область видимости определяеться, не для скрытия метода, а для разграничения прав(доступа) к определёному методу. Что лежит в основе принципа `Абстракции`. Ваш вопрос идёт в разрез c принципами oop. В данном конкретном примере или случае вы не сможете вызвать этот метод через `$this` или `new self` и т.д. Так как это нарушает принципы, этого ооп. Как минимум вы должны изменить методу область видимости и вызывать как 'new static' или 'new self' и позже вызвать от объекта, или вызывать метод как есть.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Обращение `self` идёт как классу, а не конкретному объекту этого класса. А у класса есть этот метод. Хотя выбросит ошибку о вызове не статического метода как статический.
2. `$this` - указатель на конкретный объект класса. `self` - указатель на класс в общем. В статических методах, по очевидным причинам, быть не может указателя на конкретный объект, вот и ошибка.